# Hide/Fake src in iframe, which cannot be found in DOM/inspected element

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

Original:

```
<iframe src="www.youtube.com/embed/Abvkxjkvd"frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="695" height="400"  ;w=695&amp;h=400" allowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>
```

After

```
<iframe src="Fhkvhjnbhgo" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="695" height="400"  ;w=695&amp;h=400" allowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>
```

Is there a method to change the iframe like above?

Comment: if you want, community help you then you have to give more detail.

Comment: sorry, if your browser can access it, its public, you can't hide it

Comment: Yes, it is easy to change the URL, you just showed us. It probably won't work anymore after you did that.

Comment: Listen to @Ghost .If your browser can access it, there is no way of hiding that information. The user can still use right click and get the url of the frame. You can prevent right click, but the user can still use F12. You can prevent F12, and the user can still use infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to hide the source of an iframe, as it is publicly accessible by the browser.

The only way to go around this would be so set up some sort of "shell". Lets say you are trying to show google in an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" />
```

But you don't want it to show google's address.

You could create a file name iframe.php:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```

And then show that file in your frame:

```
<iframe src="iframe.php" />
```

Note however that this can limit the expected functionality of the iframed website.

Comment: Even if it's OP's lucky day and this doesn't effect the functionality at all, most websites use meta tags with og:url or canonical properties nowadays. So beware of what you are stepping into before you decide on using this method.

Comment: Agreed @modu. I wasn't trying to pitch this as a best practice. My answer is still "no, there is no way to hide the source".

Comment: Thanks @Ole Haugset. it cannot be changed on the html/DOM(client side), but any idea on server side?<iframe src="iframe.php" /> this will show the link. but not the iframe.php wording only.

Comment: It can definitly not be changed on the server side. Server delivers data (html) to the client once. Then the client renders that data into a website. Any user can then inspect the DOM and see what source is set for the iframe. Like my answer states, there is no way to hide to source, the best you can do it mask it like my answer, but even that is a bad solution as it might cause the website your are trying to iframe to break.

Comment: Thanks. How about use Blob function to hide the Link,                                     <video id="dmp_Video" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" x-webkit-airplay="allow" operadetachedviewtitle="EP17 — Dailymotion" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="" src="blob:https://www.dailymotion.com/ed39d75c-eab8-4981-8e36-26fc72ea7810"></video>                                                                                                   But There is no a new document showing the the link of dailymorion. how to do that?